# What's LinkObject error about, and what may have caused it?

Tags: warning-messages

I've been running a simulation on a server, using parallezation, suddenly I got this error message:

```
LinkObject::linkw:     Unable to write data to closed link 
    LinkObject[/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/Executables/wolfram
      -subkernel -noinit -nopaclet -wstp, 96, 11].

Kernels::rdead:     Subkernel connected through KernelObject[11, local] appears dead.

LaunchKernels::clone:     Kernel KernelObject[11, local, <defunct>] resurrected as 
    KernelObject[17, local].
```

Afterwards, the programme starts giving several errors of the type

```
Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix 
                7            6            7           7            6
    {{1.56499 10 , 3.88419 10 , 1.47829 10 , 1.4474 10 , 3.59235 10 , 
                7           7            6                    7            7
      1.36722 10 , 1.4207 10 , 3.52609 10 , <<30>>, 1.33088 10 , 1.36087 10 , 
                6            7
      3.37759 10 , 1.28548 10 }, <<40>>, {<<42>>}} may contain significant
     numerical errors.

Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix 
              7            6            7            7            6
    {{2.516 10 , 6.16733 10 , 2.37715 10 , 2.11168 10 , 5.17626 10 , 
                7            7            6                    7
      1.99515 10 , 2.15432 10 , 5.28077 10 , <<30>>, 1.82282 10 , 
                7            6            7
      1.86818 10 , 4.57938 10 , 1.76509 10 }, <<40>>, {<<42>>}} may contain
     significant numerical errors.

Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix 
                7           6           7            7            6
    {{3.17716 10 , 7.6422 10 , 3.0029 10 , 2.71563 10 , 6.53206 10 , 
                7           7            6                    7            7
      2.56668 10 , 2.6591 10 , 6.39608 10 , <<30>>, 2.46368 10 , 2.45544 10 , 
               6            7
      5.9062 10 , 2.32076 10 }, <<40>>, {<<42>>}} may contain significant
     numerical errors.

General::stop: Further output of Inverse::luc
     will be suppressed during this calculation. From KernelObject[17, local]: Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix 
               7           6            7            7            6
    {{2.2294 10 , 5.6294 10 , 2.10524 10 , 1.92622 10 , 4.86383 10 , 
                7            7            6            7
      1.81894 10 , 1.99442 10 , 5.03605 10 , 1.88334 10 , <<14>>, 
                7            7           6            7
      1.91667 10 , 2.03254 10 , 5.1323 10 , 1.91934 10 }, <<26>>} may contain
     significant numerical errors. From KernelObject[15, local]: Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix 
               7           6            7            7            6
    {{2.2294 10 , 5.6294 10 , 2.10524 10 , 2.03207 10 , 5.13112 10 , 
               7            7            6          7                    7
      1.9189 10 , 1.97817 10 , 4.99502 10 , 1.868 10 , <<14>>, 1.98409 10 , 
                7            6            7
      1.91763 10 , 4.84215 10 , 1.81083 10 }, <<26>>} may contain significant (...)
```

Until the 1st message, the simulation had been running for a couple of days without any problem.

First, are both related? If so, what may have caused this? If not, what caused the 1st one?

Is there a way to find out? Or how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like one of the subkernels may have crashed.

Comment: @Szabolcs But was it due to my programming, or it's a Mathematica Issue?

Comment: It *should* not be possible to trigger a crash by evaluating Mathematica code. Almost certainly a Mathematica issue.